# How to parse multilevel xml in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

can you help me with this program i'm trying to parse an xml file with two levels (i don't know the term so i call that way) here's the sample of my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<countries>
<country>
    <countryname>Philippines</countryname>
<subsidiaries>
    <subsidiary>
           <name>Sart Philippines Inc.</name>
           <address>Unit 10-A The World Empire Building, 330 Senator Gil Puyat Avenue  Philippines, Philippines</address>
           <phone>+63.2.929</phone>
           <fax>+63.932</fax>
           <email>enquiry.philippines@sarts.com</email>
           <website>http://www.sartorius-mechatronics.com.ph</website>
    </subsidiary>
</subsidiaries>
</country>
<country>
    <countryname>Denmark</countryname>
    <subsidiaries>
        <subsidiary>
           <name>Stedim Nordic A|S</name>
           <address>Hoerskaetten 6d 2630 Taastrup, Denmark</address>
           <phone>+45.7023.4400</phone>
           <fax>+45.4630.4030</fax>
           <email>ne.customersupport@sartorius.com</email>
           <website></website>
        </subsidiary>
        <subsidiary>
           <name>Nordic A|S</name>
           <address>Hoerskaetten 6D 2630 Taastrup, Denmark</address>
           <phone>+45.7523.8700</phone>
           <fax>+45.4130.4020</fax>
           <email>ne.customersupport@sartorius.com</email>
           <website></website>
       </subsidiary>
     </subsidiaries>
   </country>
</countries>
```

What i was planning to do was you choose a country, then you choose a subsidiary to view it's info. I was able to parse it but i was not able to show the Stedim Nordic A|S subsidiary.

here is my parser class

```
@implementation Parser

-(id)initParser
{
    if (self == [super init])
    {
        app = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:    (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"countries"])
    {
        app.listArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    }
  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"country"])
    {
        theList = [[List alloc]init];

    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (!currentElementValue)
    {
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:string];
    }
    else
    {
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:    (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

   if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"country"])
    {
        [app.listArray addObject:theList];
    }

    else {

         if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"countryname"]) {
            theList.countryname = currentElementValue;
        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"])
        {
            theList.name = currentElementValue;
        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"address"])
        {
            theList.address = currentElementValue;
        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"phone"])
        {
            theList.phone = currentElementValue;
        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"fax"])
        {
            theList.fax = currentElementValue;
        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"email"])
        {
            theList.email = currentElementValue;
        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"website"])
        {
            theList.website = currentElementValue;

      }

       currentElementValue = nil;

    }


}
@end
```

I can't explain it well but i hope you can help me , if you can send me a link for a tutorial for this kind of issues i would really appreciate it

Comment: Create an array of customModelClass, go on to read and create object and add to the array. check if didEndElement is same as didStartElement....

Comment: What is the issue ? What happened when you done it ?

Comment: @AKV: he is doing the same, check `[app.listArray addObject:theList];`

Comment: @MidhunMP: He asked same question yesterday only. I asked him to us xpath, he again asking same question, should I post my parser for my xml ???? But I cant do it in comments. If I post it as answers, I will get downvotes..

Comment: @MidhunMP : But no one answered it...it contained only comments, now that question is removed :D

Comment: @AKV: I think his code is ok, but he didn't mentioned what happened when he used that piece of code :) I added comment, but didn't get any comment :)

Comment: You could use NSXMLDocument

Comment: @AKV if it's ok with you, will you please send me your parser on my email?

Comment: @Tbt-lionArmanCapistrano: I cant find your email id.

Comment: @AKV arman.capistrano@yahoo.com

Comment: @MidhunMP it's working but it doesn't display "Stedim Nordic A|S" i think it's being overlap by "Nordix A|S" when i add theList to my array

Comment: @Tbt-lionArmanCapistrano: I found a solution for your problem. Will post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because on your second `country` element there is two `subsidiary`.
So you need to modify your code like:

You need another `NSString` for holding the `Country Name`. Because there is a single Country name element for your two `subsidiary`.

```
NSString *temp = nil;

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:    (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"countries"])
    {
        app.listArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"subsidiary"])
    {
        theList = [[List alloc]init];
    }
}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:    (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

   if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"subsidiary"])
    {
        theList.countryname = temp;
        [app.listArray addObject:theList];
    }
    else
    {

         if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"countryname"])
         {
            temp = currentElementValue;
         }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"])
        {
            theList.name = currentElementValue;
        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"address"])
        {
            theList.address = currentElementValue;
        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"phone"])
        {
            theList.phone = currentElementValue;
        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"fax"])
        {
            theList.fax = currentElementValue;
        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"email"])
        {
            theList.email = currentElementValue;
        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"website"])
        {
            theList.website = currentElementValue;
        }
        currentElementValue = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked! i can now view "Stedim Nordic A|S" but it displays two "denmark" hmmmmm

Comment: @Tbt-lionArmanCapistrano: because there is only one country name for those two. That's why I write it like this.

Comment: Any idea how can i put this in a table view cell? @Midhum MP

Comment: in cellForRowAtIndexPath List *t = [app.listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; and cell.textLabel.text = t.name ;

Answer (score 0):

Well you can call the parser recursively. If you know what you are looking for search if it is available and take its value if present. i would suggest you to look into **gdata xml parser**